# How to resolve a redirect 301 in .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

i need to redirect this links:

Old link 1: https://www.example.com/folder/page/ (italian version)

Old link 2: https://www.example.com/folder/en/page/ (english version)

Old link 3: https://www.example.com/folder/de/page/ (deutsch version)

into this links:

New link 1: https://www.example2.com/it/page/

New link 2: https://www.example2.com/en/page/

New link 3: https://www.example2.com/de/page/

I try to put this instructions in my .htaccess file:

```
Redirect 301 https://www.example.com/folder/page/ https://www.example2.com/it/page/

Redirect 301 https://www.example.com/folder/en/page/ https://www.example2.com/en/page/

Redirect 301 https://www.example.com/folder/de/page/ https://www.example2.com/de/page/
```

(the name of the page from old site and new site are different)

The redirect works only in italian version, while in english and deutsch version doesn't work.

How can i resolve the problem?

Comment: This is not an issue with the redirection rules, but apparently with either the old references are different to what you claim here or the new references are different to what you claim here.

Comment: No, the old references and the new references are correct, it works only with the italian version and i dont't know why

Comment: As said: the rewrite rules are correct too. Maybe you have other, additional redirection or rewriting rules implemented which might interfere here? You will have to dig deeper: Enable rewrite engine logging to learn what is actually going on in your rewriting engine. See the official documentation of the apache rewrite module for details on how to do that.